# Mongo DB query on multiple conditions

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to do a simple query based on two conditions in MongoDB using pymongo.

I am using the sample restaurants data set from the tutorial documentation. I have:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo
import pandas as pd

client = MongoClient()

db = client.test

cursor = db.restaurants.find({"$and":[{'borough':"Manhattan"},{"grades":{'grade':"A"}}]}

for record in cursor:
    print record
```

I am just trying to print all the restaurants in Manhattan with a grade of 'B.' But this pulls back no results.  I have also tried

```
cursor = db.restaurants.find({"borough":"Manhattan", "grades.grade":"B"})
```

but this will only filter by the first condition and won't filter by the "grade."  It's exactly how it is laid out in the documentation but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an example doc you're expecting to find?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in the second condition. `grades` is a [subarray of grades](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitations), use `$elemMatch`:

```
db.restaurants.find({"$and": [{"borough": "Manhattan"}, {"grades": {"$elemMatch": {"grade": "A"}}}]})
```

Works for me.

Comment: No dice. still pulls back all the grades.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it worked for me with the following syntax:

```
result = db.mycollection.find({"$and": [{"key1": value1}, {"key2": value2}]})
```

I have multiple records with the same value under `key1`, but I want the only one with specific value on `key2`. It seems to work for me.