# How to query mongodb with Pymongo to get results based on multiple conditions on the same field

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo collection that contains data like:

```
{'email': 'test1@gmail.com'}
{'email': 'test2@gmail.com'}
{'email': 'test3@gmail.com'}
```

I want to get the the result of email that is `test1@gmail.com` and `test2@gmail.com`, eg:

```
[{'email':'test1gmail.com'},{'email':'test2gmail.com'}]
```

is there a way I can do this with Pymongo's find?

I've tried using:

```
test.find({'email': 'test1@gmail.com', 'email':'test2@gmail.com'})
```

But I think that's only getting the email `test2@gmail.com` and not `'test1@gmail.com`. If I do:

```
test.find({'email': 'test2@gmail.com', 'email':'test1@gmail.com'})
```

That only gives me the results for `test1@gmail.com`.

Thought I would give `$or` a try based on [Mongo DB query on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832109/mongo-db-query-on-multiple-conditions.):

```
test.find({"$or":[{'seller_email': 'test2@gmail.com', 'seller_email':'test1@gmail.com'}]})
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.

I looked through the docs: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html, but I didn't see it.

I know you can do it from mongo's cli: [MongoDB query with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389823/mongodb-query-with-multiple-conditions),
but I need it to do it via pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue, using the `$or` keyword should have worked. I've missed/misplaced some `{}`.

Should be:

```
test.find({"$or":[{'seller_email': 'test2@gmail.com'}, {'seller_email':'test1@gmail.com'}]})
```

instead of:

```
test.find({"$or":[{'seller_email': 'test2@gmail.com', 'seller_email':'test1@gmail.com'}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you better referring to the official mongodb help pages, see here for querying methods: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-documents/ and refer to the ‘Or’ conditions which I believe would solve your problem.

Comment: I see you’ve actually now solved it, I was too slow!